# Google Analytics: tracking a custom dimension on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics

I have some problems regarding custom dimensions with Google Analytics on iOS.
I already set up my custom dimension in the web interface of GA. But if I send my custom dimension in the AppDelegate on initialization of the GA tracker it doesn't show up like expected.

```
id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
[tracker set:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:1] value:@"testValue"];
[tracker send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] set:@"testValue" forKey:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:1]] build]];
```

Does anybody experience similar problems?

Answer (score 1):

```
> I hope it's help you.
// Call this on didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self startGoogleAnalyticsTracking];
    [self performSelector:@selector(sendGoogleAnalyticsStartup)     withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
       // --------- Enter your code here
----------//
return YES;
}

- (void)startGoogleAnalyticsTracking {
    @try {
//        self.googleAnalyticsTracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:”PASTE YOUR TRACKING ID HERE”];
        // Optional: automatically send uncaught exceptions to Google Analytics.
        [GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
        // Optional: set Google Analytics dispatch interval to e.g. 20 seconds.
        [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 10;
        // Optional: set debug to YES for extra debugging information.
        [GAI sharedInstance].debug = YES;

        // **** REPLACE Tracking Id with your own GA Tracking Id **** //
        // Create tracker instance.Tracking Id
        id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"Tracking Id"];
        [tracker sendView:@"Application Loaded"];
    }@catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"exception:%@",exception);
    }
}



- (void)sendGoogleAnalyticsStartup {
        @try {
            [self.googleAnalyticsTracker sendEventWithCategory:@"Application Events" withAction:nil withLabel:@"Tracking Starts" withValue:nil];
        }@catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"exception=%@",exception);
        }
    }


 - (void)stopGoogleAnalyticsTracking {
        @try {
            [self.googleAnalyticsTracker sendEventWithCategory:@"Application Events" withAction:nil withLabel:@"Tracking Suspended /Stopped" withValue:nil];
        }@catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"exception=%@",exception);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer but I already found the "problem" which wasn't really a problem. I did set up everything correctly. But Google Analytics needs some time to analyze the data. It takes really long before it shows up in the web interface, so for everyone experiencing similar problems: be patient!

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the "problem" wasn't really one. I did set up everything correctly. But Google Analytics needs some time to evaluate the data. It takes really long (48hrs+) before it shows up in the web interface. So for everyone experiencing similar problems: be patient!